# How to get Object key value in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How to get key from Object in vue.js

**this is template**

```
<div id="app" class="container">
        <ul class="list-group mt-5">
            <li v-for='product in products' class="list-group-item">
                {{ product.title }}           
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**this is script**

```
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            'products':{
                1:{title: 'The history of web 1'},
                2:{title: 'The next web'}
            },
        }
    })
</script>
```

How to get '1' , '2' in products ?

Comment: If your products are just 1, 2, 3, 4... consider using an array. Does `v-for="(value, key, index) in products"` work for you? See [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object)

Comment: @ggorlen thanks for answer :D {{ key }} works for me very well.